# exceptions in program

Tags: android

I tried to execute the following piece of code.If i enter the site names with http [for eg:`http://www.google.com`] am getting correct output.Otherwise I am getting force close. Even I am catching the activitynotfoundexception then also I am getting `ActivityNotFoundException`.

Help me.

```
try {
    Button browse=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Browse);
    browseURl=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.BrowseUrl);
    browse.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent invokeURI=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(browseURl.getText().toString()));
            startActivity(invokeURI);
        }
    });
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    // TODO: handle exception

    Log.e("BrowseURI","Failed Browsing the given URI",ex);
}
```

Comment: Check logs to see what exception it throws. May be something like URISyntaxException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to catch the exception within your onClick event, because you're getting the exception after you've clicked, not when you're hooking the event handler.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent invokeURI=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(browseURl.getText().toString()));
        try {
            startActivity(invokeURI);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Log.e("BrowseURI","Failed Browsing the given URI",ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Scottie..thanks....So where i have to place try-catch block.....can u pls explain it....i didnt get your point.....

Comment: `try {startActivity(invokeURI);} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) { Log.e(...); }`

Comment: @Scottie....thanks a lot.....nice to meet u....i need one more help from you...can you suggest me a good book to learn core and advanced android...

Comment: Glad that did the trick for you! Could you mark this question as answered? As far as books go [Pro Android 2](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-Android-2-Sayed-Hashimi/dp/1430226595/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1306232226&sr=8-5) coupled with the Android SDK documentation itself is a good combination to get started with. Cheers